# Как данные из ячейки excel экспортировать в переменную JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

В excel есть две ячейки A и B в которые из другой программы по DDE приходят числовые значения.

Нужно при A*3 < B или B*3 < А присылать сообщения в телеграм, вотсап или на почту. Каким образом лучше реализовать такую задачу ? Можно ли в самом excel реализовать отправку сообщений ?

Comment: В самом* Excel* реализовать отправку сообщений на почту можно с помощью *VBA*, но не *JS*